# Typescript: ES6 Map + index signature = no error?

Tags: typescript

Considering the following code:

```
const map = new Map<string, string>();
map['someKey'] = 'someValue';
```

It compiles fine, despite the fact that Map definition doesn't have the index signature (as far as I could find; and, in fact, in ES6 it doesn't have one documented too). What's the problem, and is it possible to force the error in such cases?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your tsconfig.json, do `"strict": true`, which sets `"noImplicitAny": true`, and upon doing so, you'll receive this error:

> [ts] Element implicitly has an 'any' type because type 'Map' has no index signature.

[Try it out here.](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#src=const%20map%20%3D%20new%20Map%3Cstring%2C%20string%3E()%3B%0D%0Amap%5B'someKey'%5D%20%3D%20'someValue'%3B) Click "Options" and turn on the `noImplicitAny` flag. Also make sure `"suppressImplicitAnyIndexErrors"` is set to `false`.

Comment: Strangely enough, but we have the `"noImplicitAny": true` in our tsconfig.json directly. Can it be overwritten somewhere?

Comment: It's difficult to override a tsconfig by mistake, but yeah, another tsconfig with an `"extends"` property could be overriding it. It's also possible your editor / build pipeline isn't picking it up for whatever reason, since the strict flag is disabled by default

Comment: OK, I see now I was blind not to see the `"suppressImplicitAnyIndexErrors": true` line in the same config. On changing this to `false` your answer did work, so accepting.